# Automate Apple in-app purchase/subscription using backend APIs

Tags: java

I am interested in using Apple sandbox users for my automation, and I want to bypass the UI and execute the automation using the APIs. I have found the APIs to list users, modify users, and clear purchase history, but I am not sure if there is a way to create and delete users programmatically. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/sandbox_testers
Currently, our app calls Apple to get the payment receipt, and then our internal workflows are triggered based on the response received from Apple. Is there a way to bypass UI and achieve the same thing using the backend APIs for sandbox user accounts?
I also need some clarification on how to generate the JWT token for authorization purposes. Do I need to regenerate the JWT token every 30 days?
Thank you for your time and consideration.

I work for Amazon and went through internal documentation, Apple documentation and also had several discussion with my teammates who worked on implementing the features.